# Spring Batch how can I access the stepExection in a Partitioner

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have the following TicketProductPartitioner class and context. I've set the bean scope to step and am setting the reference

```
<!-- Ticket partitioner into 15 steps -->
<bean id="ticketProductPartitioner" parent="abstractAttributionStep" class="a.b.c.batch.TicketProductPartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}"/>
</bean>
```

My class is

```
public class TicketProductPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    private StepExecution stepExecution = null;

    /**
     * Create a ExecutionContext for each sub ticket of todays job
     */
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        Date runDate = (Date) getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().get(AttributionParameter.RUN_DATE.name());
        logger.info("Start TicketProductPartitioner job for run_date "+runDate);
```

but it appears the stepExecution reference is always null. If this was a simple processor bean this wiring would work, so what is different now that i'm in a partition step?

Answer (score 1):

StepExecution is not directly bindable using spEL, but must be injected letting  `TicketProductPartitioner` implements `StepExecutionListener` of marking a partitioner method with `@BeforeStep` annotation; this is why your class field is null.